# adding new rows in a loop with rbind.fill

Tags: r

Im looking of a way to `rbind.fill` data frames in a loop. My desired result looks like this:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(101)
df1=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
              "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
              "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))
x=df1[,1]+10
new_variable=data.frame(var1=x)
rbind.fill(df1,new_variable)
```

I need to make a loop that automatically add a string as new rows to multiple data frames. Here is an example:

```
library(plyr)
#to be sure everyone has same output
set.seed(101)
#example dfs
df1=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
              "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
              "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))


df2=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
               "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
               "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))

df3=data.frame("var1"=runif(18,min=0,max=1),
               "index2"=c(rep(c("A","B","C"),6)),
               "index1"=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,9)))

#df names
df.names=c("df1","df2","df3")

#loop
for (i in 1:length(df.names)){
  x=get(df.names[i])[,1]+10
  new_variable=data.frame(var1=x)
  #my idea of what binding code should look like
  rbind.fill(get(df.names[i]),new_variable)
  #to print results
  print(get(df.names[i]))
  }
```

As you can see data frames (`df1`, `df2` and `df3`) does not contain additional rows. How to fix this? Keep in mind I want add rows to old dfs permanently so I can later write them.

Important note: it has to be `rbind.fill` function or any other method that binds data frames by rows with different column numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all data frames in a list and apply, i.e.

```
library(plyr)

l1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df[0-9]+'))
l1 <- lapply(l1, function(i){m1 <- i[1] + 10; 
                       new_vars <- data.frame(var1 = m1); 
                       rbind.fill(i, new_vars)})
```

Comment: You can simplify it to `plyr::rbind.fill(x, data.frame(var1 = x[,1] + 10))` imo. See my answer (will delete that in a couple of minutes)

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong - this code does not add rows to my dfs but only printed new dfs. I need to add permanently rows to existing data frames (so i could write them as csv for example). I update this information to my question.

Comment: Kane ta assign pisw sto `l1` re patrida :). i.e. `l1 <- lapply(l1, function(i){.....})`

Comment: Could you add to your post also `for` method? I am not very familiar with `lapply` yet, so Im little confused :( Thank you in advance